# Launch configuration ANSIBuffer (1) references non-existing project ooo

Tags: java, eclipse

I imported project and when i run project  got this

```
Launch configuration ANSIBuffer (1) references non-existing project ooo.
```

and when i run class as java application got this

```
Selection doesn't contain main type
```

I'm on Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 0):

The project you have imported depends on another project called 'ooo' which you haven't imported.

Eclipse cannot find a `main` method anywhere in the project.

Comment: but i don't have project called ooo!

Comment: There is a 'launch configuration' in the project you imported which contains a reference to a project called 'ooo'. Where did this project you imported come from? You may have to find this 'ooo' project.

Comment: the project called storm-starter form github